# Convert generator object to a dictionary

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
# library to extract cookies in a http message
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

... do connect to httpserver etc

cdict = ((c.name,c.value) for c in cj)
```

The problem with this code is cdict is a generator.  But I want to simply create a dictionary.  How can I change the last line to assign to a dictionary?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension. (Introduced in Python 2.7)

`cdict = {c.name:c.value for c in cj}`

For example,

```
>>> {i:i*2 for i in range(10)}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12, 7: 14, 8: 16, 9: 18}
```

Here is the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) which introduced Dictionary Comprehensions. It may be useful.

**If you are on something below Python 2.7.** - Build a list of key value pairs and call `dict()` on them, something like this.

```
>>> keyValList = [(i, i*2) for i in range(10)]
>>> keyValList
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8), (5, 10), (6, 12), (7, 14), (8, 16), (9, 18)]
>>> dict(keyValList)
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12, 7: 14, 8: 16, 9: 18}
```

**OR** Just pass your generator to the [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) method. Something like this

```
>>> dict((i, i*2) for i in range(10))
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12, 7: 14, 8: 16, 9: 18}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [*dict comprehension*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
cdict = {c.name: c.value for c in cj}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the easiest way is just using the `dict()` constructor. Here an example:

```
def create_dummy_generator():
for i in range(10):
    yield i, i*2
x = create_dummy_generator()
y = dict(x)
type(x)
# <class 'generator'>
print(x)
# <generator object create_generator at 0x7fde3c562f90>
type(y)
# <class 'dict'>
print(y)
# {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12, 7: 14, 8: 16, 9: 18}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/): `{c.name:c.value for c in cj}`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
cdict = {c.name:c.value for c in cj}
```